# Unknown command on Gmail gem

Tags: ruby, gmail

I'm trying to get my emails using the Gmail gem ([source](https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail)) with the next call:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize account, credentials
    @gmail = Gmail.connect(account, credentials)
  end

  def get_attachments received_at, options
    mails = @gmail.inbox.find(
      :to => options[:to],
      :has=>:attachments,
      :before => options[:end_date],
      :after => received_at
     )
     #more code
   end
end
```

`@gmail` is a valid instance of `Gmail` class, and this call raises sometimes the next error:

```
Unknown command v2if4084974eef.9
```

The command (v2if4084974eef.9) changes in every call I make.

What am I doing wrong?

[Edit]

The error raised in specs is this

```
1)
Net::IMAP::BadResponseError in 'MailFacade get_data should return an array'
Unknown command v17if3069084anm.44
```

Comment: The only backtrace available :S. The error I think is in the server  (it's a Net::IMAP::BadResponseError), but I don't know why is raised. When it raises again, I'll post the #find arguments used in the call

Comment: I've just used the Mail gem and it raised an "Net::IMAP::NoResponseError:  Too many simultaneous connections. (Failure)" error. The problem is now clear, and it's not in my code. Sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and I found the answer to this in the last comment on this link:

https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail/issues/36

You just have to follow these steps:
1. Go to your Google account settings: myaccount.google.com
2. Click on "connected apps & sites" option.
3. Turn "Allow less secure apps" to "ON" (near the bottom of the page).

That's it, at least works for me, hope it works for you aswell.

Greetings from Bolivia!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow "less secure" apps to use your Gmail account (as @xXAngelJinXx mentioned). Since Google changed the UI, now one needs to do the following:

1. Go to your Google account settings: https://myaccount.google.com
2. Click on "Security" on the left
3. Scroll down to "Less secure app access"
4. Click on "Turn on access (not recommended)"
5. Turn it to "ON".